# Can I use usb wlan adaptor as a hotspot?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, internet-connection, connection-sharing

I want to know if I can use a USB Wlan adaptor as a Hotspot to share my wired internet of PC using the bridged connection? If this is possible, where would one search for quality brand and model of USB wlan adaptors?

Comment: Seems to depend on the software provided with the adapter.  An old AirLink101 802.11g adapter came with Windows software that can turn the PC into a wireless access point.  A N*****r adapter did not.

Comment: can i use netgear router ....can you suggest a good software name except connectify as its a crap.

Comment: Before you start passing judgment, you should get familiar with the signal strengths and good/poor setup that you may have.  Try using [inSSIDer](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) to get a handle on your wireless environment.